# Fetch data from database in Laravel 9 using Vue js 3

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

I wanted to read the data from the database and display it in the app.

I'm calling it like this :

```
 <h2 class="lowongan1" v-for="value in list_lowongan"> {{ value.title }}</h2>
 <p class="descJob1" v-for="value in list_lowongan">{{ value.body }}</p>
```

The script

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      'form': {
        title: '',
        body: '',
      },

      list_lowongan: []
    };
  },

    mounted() {
        console.log('on mounted');
        axios.get('post/list').then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.list_lowongan = response.data
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    },
```

The problem is, when I call it like that, It displays all the title in the database and the body in the database tables.

How can I make it so that it only display 1 title for each h2  class ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a wrapping div to hold your content and then loop over the div like so:

```
<div v-for="value in list_lowongan">
  <h2 class="lowongan1"> {{ value.title }}</h2>
  <p class="descJob1">{{ value.body }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two for-loops independent of each other so they'll stack by themselves

You just need one for-loop to display a list of where each `title` and `body` are together

You can form it this way:

```
<div v-for="value in list_lowongan">
    <h2>{{ value.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ value.body }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, No need to use multiple `v-for` loops for same data iteration. Instead you can achieve that by applying `v-for` in a wrapper element and then prints the object values inside that wrapper element.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list_lowongan: []
  },
  mounted() {
    this.list_lowongan = [{
        title: 'Title 1',
      body: 'Body 1'
    }, {
        title: 'Title 2',
      body: 'Body 2'
    }, {
        title: 'Title 3',
      body: 'Body 3'
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(value, index) in list_lowongan" :key="index">
    <h2>{{ value.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ value.body }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```